# display data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to display srfno, datecreated,clientname and returneditem in  a table. srfno,datecreated and clientname were from sales table while returneditem is on sales_item table. Tables are related through srfno. I was able to display srfno,date and clientname but not returneditem. 
Pls find what's wrong and missing in my code. Any explanation and help will do. Thanks.
Code for loading data:

```
if(isset($_GET['sn'])){
    $ppid = $_GET['sn'];
    $sqlLoader="Select sales.srfno, sales.clientid, sales.datecreated, 
                sales_item.retdesc 
                from sales 
                RIGHT JOIN sales_item ON sales.srfno==sales_item.srfno";
    $resLoader=$con->prepare($sqlLoader);
    $resLoader->execute(array($ppid));      

    while($rowLoader = $resLoader->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $sn= $rowLoader['srfno'];
        $dcr= $rowLoader['datecreated'];
        $cid=$rowLoader['clientid'];
        $retid=$rowLoader['srfno'];
        $retdesc=$rowLoader['retdesc'];
```

Here's my code  for displaying srf,date,clientname and returned item. I am using some pdo here:

```
$sql="Select sales.srfno, sales.datecreated, sales.clientid, sales_item.retdesc 
      from sales 
      RIGHT JOIN sales_item ON sales.srfno=sales_item.srfno";
$res=$db->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();    
$str="<div><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display' id='tbl' class='jtable' align='center'>";
$str.="<thead><tr><th width='250px'>SRF No</th><th>Date Created</th><th align='center'>Client Name</th><th>Returned Item</th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>";

while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $str.="<tr><td><center>".$row['srfno']."</center></td>";
    $str.="<td align='center'>".$row['datecreated']."</td>";

    $sclientid=$row['clientid'];
        $cli="Select name from client where clientid=$sclientid";
        $client=$db->prepare($cli);
        $client->execute(); 
        while($clie= $client->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $clientname=$clie['name'];
        }

    $item=$row['srfno'];
        $itemret="Select retdesc from sales_item where srfno=$item";
        $itemreturn=$db->prepare($itemret);
        $itemreturn->execute();
        while($return=$itemreturn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $retdesc=$return['retdesc'];
        }

    $str.="<td align='center'>".$clientname."</td>";
    $str.="<td align='center'>".$retdesc."</td>";
```

Comment: where are you selecting returneditem ?

Comment: @echo_Me at sales_item table

Comment: You're misusing PDO - you should be using parameterized queries even here.  You're likely not vulnerable to SQL Injection in **this** instance, given usual types for join keys.  You shouldn't need to go after `sales_item` again, given it'd be present in the original result set (perhaps just use an `ORDER BY`?).  And I'd probably have added a join for `client` as well.  Oh, `RIGHT JOIN` is rarely used - `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` tends to be used, for preference, although you could probably get away with a regular `(INNER) JOIN` here...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i got what u said. What i did was I excluded the process of getting $retdesc. I just called $retdesc by using .$row['retdesc']. thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Echo_me has it correct. You aren't selecting returned item in your query:

```
$sql="Select sales.srfno, sales.datecreated, sales.clientid, sales_item.retdesc 
from sales 
RIGHT JOIN sales_item 
ON sales.srfno=sales_item.srfno";
```

Add the item to your query

```
$sql="Select sales.srfno, sales.datecreated, sales.clientid, sales_item.retitem, sales_item.retdesc 
from sales 
RIGHT JOIN sales_item 
ON sales.srfno=sales_item.srfno";
```

Comment: @echo_Me the returned item is sales_item.retdesc. it's the same and i don't have retitem for me to call it

Answer (score 0):

For those who might encounter this problem, you don't need to create another query for getting values to another table especially if you're using joins. And using join will make your life easier. Just call the variable by .$row['fieldname'] and that's it!! :) thanks to the man who help me realize what's wrong with my code. Thanks man!